# django 1.8.3 tutorial index.html template wrong to get corrent url

Tags: python, django

I'm learning Django 1.8.3 with tutorial and I came here: [Removing hardcoded URLs in templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial03/#removing-hardcoded-urls-in-templates). I followed this section and modified the `polls/template/polls/index.html` like this:

```
{% if latest_question_list %}
<ul>
{% for question in latest_question_list %}
    <!--<li><a href="/polls/{{ question.id }}/">{{question.question_text}}</a></li>-->
    <li><a href="{% url 'detail' question.id %}">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
{% else %}
    <p> No polls are available. </p>
{% endif %}
```

But when I access Question by clicking the URL I get 404 like this: [404 page when click a question](http://d.pr/i/1j71D).
I don't know what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Please post your urls.py and views.py so we can see how it's being matched. Also note that when django renders template tags, normal HTML comments are completely ignored (like you have it above). Consequently, if you have any errors in your code that are included in a regular HTML comment section, they will still error out. Just something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 2):

Your Django template tag ends with `% }` (on the error page that you link to), and therefore Django doesn't recognize it.

Remove the space.

Comment: Actually there's no space between `%` and `}` as I post above, and I checked my code there is no space between them for sure.

Comment: But in the error message, there is. Some way or another, Django is using a template that has a space there.